# QML import later module version only if available?

Tags: qt, import, qml

I have some work-in-progress QML code that currently requires QtCharts 2.1 from Qt 5.6. However, we are currently running our code using Qt 5.5.1, which only has QtCharts 2.0.

Is it possible to check in QML what the latest available version of QtCharts on the system is, *then* perform the proper import, and handle any associated special-case logic appropriately? I'd like to finish implementing my feature and merge it to the integration branch *without* breaking the GUI functionality on machines that have 5.5.1. (I'm okay having *this new feature* be broken for now, but currently it appears that the entire QML engine fails to load when a QML file contains invalid imports.)

Out of sheer indomitable hope, I tried the following:

```
try {
    import QtCharts 2.1
} catch {
    import QtCharts 2.0
}
```

... which of course did not work, as `try` is not part of the QML root-level syntax.

---

A related-but-not-quite-duplicate question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27440425/1858225). The distinction is that the OP for that question is apparently satisfied with using a `Loader` to dynamically load a *single QML element*. I don't think this trick can be used in my case, though, because `QtCharts` 2.0 and 2.1 contain the same QML element types, and in any case I don't know how to import "the latest" QtCharts available (as far as I can tell, the `import` statement syntax *requires* a specific version number).

**EDIT:** As per my answer below, the `Loader` workaround *does* apparently work. So I suppose this is a duplicate after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional imports were requested as a feature for Qt 4.7, but have not been implemented yet; see the [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-16854) for details.

However, it's possible to use a `Loader` to make sure that the `import` failure does not prevent the rest of the GUI from loading. This is outlined in one of the comments in the bug-report discussion.

**FAILING CASE:**

```
// MyContainer.qml
Item {
    AlwaysAvailableType {
        // ... etc
    }
    SometimesNonworkingType {
        id: nonworking_thing
        // ... FAILS to load!
    }
}
```

Here, we assume that `SometimesNonworkingType.qml` contains the `import` statement that will fail on some systems but not others. When the QML engine tries to load `MyContainer`, it will fail, causing the *entire QML loading operation to fail*.

**FIXED VERSION:**

```
// MyContainer.qml
Item {
    AlwaysAvailableType {
        // ... etc
    }
    Loader {
        source: "SometimesNonworkingType.qml"
        property bool valid: item !== null

        id: maybeworking_thing
        // ... etc
    }
}
```

`maybeworking_thing.valid` can be used to check if the `SometimesNonworkingType` was actually successfully loaded.

(Credit for finding the bug report: [How to write conditional import statements in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27440425/1858225))

Comment: @coyotte508 Yeah, it looks like that will probably never be implemented.

Comment: @coyotte508 However, I've looked again at the proposed work-around, and it *does* work in my case.